# Getting error using fat arrow function in php

Tags: php

```php
$mul2 = fn($x) => $x * 2;
$mul2(3);
```

I  am getting an error :

> Error-  Unexpected =>,  Expected ';'.

How do I resolve the error ?

Comment: Arrow functions introduced in php7.4. I __doubt__ you have php7.4 installed.

Comment: how do I do that in php 7.4 then ?

Comment: Just like you're doing it now, just with the right version

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php

Comment: Reproduced issued: https://3v4l.org/Z2rM6  what is the environment that your php is in?  Local server? Remote server? Windows?  Can't point you in the right direction without knowing more.

Answer (score 0):

Code snippet

```
fn($x) => $x * 2
```

uses so called **arrow function**.

**Arrow functions** are introduced in **php7.4**.

If your php version is older - your option is to use `function() {}` notation:

```
$mul2 = function($x) { return $x * 2; };
echo $mul2(3); // outputs 6
```